# Copying a row in excel from one sheet to another after searching for a given value

Tags: vba, excel

Disclaimer... I am not looking for someone to code this for me, just point me in the correct direction or give me some examples I can work with.

Problem:  I have a workbook that has two pages.   the first if formatted like this

```
Hostname       Chassis Service Tag Asset Tab   Location    u   
LCLDHV003-25    PE R610 1*V4YQ1     1*1315  D3SF85.08      21
LCMNTYPXYB02    PE R610 BZ00L1      19368   x3SD04.34      36
LEMAILMIG001    PE 1950 9ZVSJ1      12078   x3SE07.12      29
LPASSCDB01-01   PE R710 3XSVH1      11415   P3SD02.22      03
```

I need to search in in the location field for a given value (example x3SD04) and then insert this row into the second table.  I need to have the existing data moved down the page.

I have seen vlookup  index, match   and some vba options.  just that everything I have tried has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim SearchString$, cl As Range, n&
    SearchString = "x3SD04"
    n = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'get row for insert copied row
    Set cl = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(SearchString) 'find range with SearchString
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then 'if SearchString exist in sheet then copy 
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(cl.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(n)
    End If
End Sub
```